# Using Magento 2 Framework for other web application

Tags: magento2

I wonder if it is possible to use Magento framework for other purpose, like making a blogging website and remove ALL e-commerce features and keep only Admin interface, dependency injection, factory, command line, the frontend stacks, ... If it is possible how can I do it? Is it worth to try?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible

see https://github.com/magento/storefront-search-ce as example (api only application)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this